# Extracting tag contents in Beautfiful Soup out of range and max recursion errors

Tags: list, recursion, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn how to scrape with Beautiful Soup.  My trial is to get company names from Alibaba.com.

My understanding is the contents of a tag are managed like lists and you can use find_all again to extract sub-elements. For example:

```
bar = soup.find_all("some", {"class" : "mainstuff"})
for foo in bar:
    print foo.contents[1].find_all("a", {"class" : "otherstuff"})
```

My problem is I can't seem to index the contents of my tag in order to extract just the names.

When I try, I get a maximum recursion depth exceeded error for [0] and an index out of range error for [1].

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.alibaba.com/products/isostatic_press.html")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

supplier = soup.find_all("a", {"class" : "dot-product"}) #Location of company name

for name in supplier:
    print name.text
```

Gives

Beijing Tianma Sling Co., Ltd.

Contact Details

Contact Supplier

Contact Details
Contact Supplier

Qinhuangdao Aidite High-Technical Ceramics Co., Ltd.

Contact Details

Contact Supplier

Contact Details
Contact Supplier

```
print name.contents
```

Gives

```
[<span class="gs1"></span>]
[u'Beijing Tianma Sling Co., Ltd.']
[]
[u'Contact Details', <i></i>]
[<i></i>]
[<span class="ico-email"></span>, u'Contact Supplier']
[]
[u'Contact Details', <i></i>]
[<span class="ico-csb"></span>, u'Contact Supplier']
[]
[<span class="gs3"></span>]
[u'Qinhuangdao Aidite High-Technical Ceramics Co., Ltd.']
[]
[u'Contact Details', <i></i>]
```

I want just the company names, but when I try

```
print name.contents[0]
```

I get RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

```
print name.contents[1]
```

Gives IndexError: list index out of range

This technique seems to work on other pages (www.yellowpages.com), so I can't figure out why I get an error now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that if `a` tag has a company name, then `name.contents` return an array of length one. So you can try this approach.

```
for name in supplier:
    if name.text and len(name.contents) == 1:
        print name.text
```